# detect link in 2nd level li and add a span, plus add class to parent li on hover

Tags: jquery, menu, find, hyperlink

I'm working on a two level unordered list menu, and so far was able to take some decent newbie steps in figuring out how to show and hide the menu using jQuery, as well as animate it a tad.

I have two issues to resolve:

1. I want to have the parent li remain
   in hover state when it is hovered
   while the mouse is hovering over its child ul
2. I'd like to detect if the parent li has a ul, and add a span between the a tags, resulting in: `<a href="#">Text <span style="addedStyle">&nbsp;</span></a>`

Here's the jQuery I'm using so far. the ".addClass("active")" doesn't seem to be doing much:

```
$(".leftMenu li:has('ul')").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass("active").children().animate({opacity: 'show'});
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active").children().hide();
    }
);
//this line is wrong and non-functional
$(".leftMenu li:has('ul > a')").append('<span class="arrowdiv">&nbsp;</span>');
```

Looking forward!

Comment: While reformatting I added a few semi-colons and removed a superfluous closing parentheses at the end of the "non functional" line maybe that was the cause.

Comment: Thanks jitter. 

I can see the benefits of breaking up the two functions, such as ease of future add-ons. The code cleanup is insightful and much appreciated. I was also able to solve my first issue and have the parent stay "active" when the child was hovered.

The non-functional line isn't causing any errors, however it doesn't seem to be doing what I want either. I'm not so sure that the js condition is 100% correct. I need to first find an a tag that's inside .leftMenu > li, only if the li has children, and then insert a span before the </a> closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Learning something new every day!

I had to find the "a" and append it to that. it simply was appending to the whole li, and I had to focus on the a, which I obviously did as so:

```
$(".leftMenu li:has('ul') > a").append('<span class="arrowdiv">&nbsp;</span>')
.parent().hover(
function(){
  $(this).addClass("active").children().animate({opacity: 'show'});
},
function(){
 $(this).removeClass("active").children().hide();
}
);
```